# 'held on to broken packages' - Steam

Tags: package-management, updates, 22.04, dependencies, steam

[![error screenshot][1]][1]

I've tried to uninstall Steam on this PC over and over again, to no avail. So that doesn't seem to be the problem. And for some reason now my PC cuts off the tops of the letters when I type here even.  Things are getting strange in Ubuntu.

I get a message that says I've **'held on to broken packages'**?

> > The following packages have unmet dependnecies:
> > libegl1:i386 : Depends: libegl-mesa):i386 but it in not installable
> > libgbm1`: Breaks: libgbm1:i386 (!=22.2.5-0ubunntu0.1-22.04.2) but 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1-22.04.2 is to be installed
> > libgbm1:i386 : Breaks libgbm1 (!= 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1) but22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1-22.04.2 is to be installed
> > libgl1-mesa-dri : Breaks: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (!= 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1-22.04.1) but 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1-22.04.1 is to be installed
> > libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 :Depends libglapi-mesa-dri:i386 (= 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1) but it isw not installable
> > Recommends: libgl1-amber-dri:i386 but it is not installable
> > Breaks: libgl1-mesa-dri (!= 22.2.5-0ubuntu.1-22.04.1) but 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1-22.04.2 is to be installed
> > libglx0:i386 :Depends: libglx-mesa:i386 but it is not installable
> > E: Unable to correct probles, you have held broken packages.

Comment: You seem to be describing two independent problems: 1) Your Steam install/uninstall issue and 2) Your version conflict ("held broken packages"). AskUbuntu works best if you ask a single, clear, answerable question, so these two problems would work better as separate questions. Happily, both questions have been asked and answered before -- try the Search box at the top of the page. Simply Search for the key terms of each error message.

Comment: Please copy/paste and format text instead of pictures of text. A picture (of text) can't be read on a text-only terminal, can't be copied from (edited, tried, and made to work), AND makes one take an action to even read your Question. Since we're all volunteers, some won't click. Please read https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: Have you tried: sudo apt --fix-broken install

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: Yall have to  understand, I'm 66 years of age, almost 67. I don't have your computer savvy nor do I know how to 'Ask' the questions "correctly."  I just ask for help from those of you that are because I support a free internet and Ubuntu has worked for me since I started using it back in 2011/   and yes I tired the sud0 apt -fix-broken install  it didn't help

Comment: You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run:
libGL.so.1
libdrm.so.2

Comment: did the fix on the 'store' thing, that fixed the problem of update store but still get a small in the middle of the desktop black screen from opening steam

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, the ecosystem of sta*ckexchange network is infamous for being unfriendly towards some segment of people and I apologize for all of us. Now, of course there's always a possibility that trial & error like this could break your system, but if you still want some input, Steam will usually need `i386` and `amd64` architecture to be installed. Do you have them installed ?

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo dpkg --add-architecture amd64
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

These are packages that Steam usually need to install :

```
Steam needs to install these additional packages:
libc6:amd64 libc6:i386 libegl1:amd64 libegl1:i386 libgbm1:amd64 libgbm1:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1:amd64 libgl1:i386 steam-libs-i386:i386
```

My advice is, to be safe just check one-by-one if each of them is installed using

```
sudo apt-get install [package_name]
```

If the package is installed, you'll get information. If no, the system will install it for you by hitting "**Y**". for example

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:amd64
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386
```

And so on for each package, if the system ask you to uninstall other things (especially "bunch" of other things, then hit "**N**" right away). At some point, you'll find out which ones are "not installable". Take notes for these packages and investigate using "`aptitude`". For example, a problematic one is "`libegl1:i386`", use

```
sudo aptitude install libegl1:i386
```

"`aptitude`" command will give you options of what available choices we can do to install this package, usually including downgrading other packages (image attached). "`aptitude`" can be very useful, but also please be careful to use it. I can't exactly give more input on what option number you should choose, because it will be different for each system. This is something that only trial & error can do.

[image]

Make sure all the packages that originally can't be installed are now all installed, do reboot (just to be safe), then try to install Steam again.