# apt install steam not working on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, steam

I am trying to use `sudo apt install steam` for my install, but I get the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-dri : Breaks: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (!= 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1) but 22.0.1-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 : Depends: libdrm-nouveau2:i386 (>= 2.4.66) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libdrm-radeon1:i386 (>= 2.4.31) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libglapi-mesa:i386 (= 22.0.1-1ubuntu2) but 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1 is to be installed
                        Recommends: libgl1-amber-dri:i386 but it is not installable
                        Breaks: libgl1-mesa-dri (!= 22.0.1-1ubuntu2) but 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1 is to be installed
 libglx-mesa0 : Breaks: libglx-mesa0:i386 (!= 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1) but 22.0.1-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
 libglx-mesa0:i386 : Depends: libglapi-mesa:i386 (= 22.0.1-1ubuntu2) but 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1 is to be installed
                     Breaks: libglx-mesa0 (!= 22.0.1-1ubuntu2) but 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

I have tried `sudo apt install steam --fix-broken` and I get the same output. Any help will be greatly appreciated and I'll try to remain on top of this post so if any clarification is needed I'll do my best to provide it.

Output of `apt policy libgl1-mesa-dri`:

```
libgl1-mesa-dri:
  Installed: 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1
  Candidate: 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     22.0.1-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['held on to broken packages' - Steam](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1469713/held-on-to-broken-packages-steam)

Comment: Something funny is going on in your system. The default version of libgl1-mesa-dri in 22.04 is 23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1 but what you are doing is asking for older versions.  Please add the output of `apt policy libgl1-mesa-dri` to your question.

Comment: @DanielT unfortunately that suggestion doesn't quite clear things up with me. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: @OrganicMarble done!

Comment: Notice that the installed version did not come from the default repos. In fact it did not come from any repo currently on your system - it is "orphaned"! So you must had had some other repo attached to your system that you removed, leaving a bunch of orphaned packages. You'll have to clean that up before you can install steam. I notice you don't have the jammy-updates repo either. Basically, your sources are a mess.  You might be able to add the jammy-updates repo and run updates, and it might fix some of these problems as new versions are added, but then again it may just make more problems.

Comment: @OrganicMarble oof yeah, using `deborphan --guess-all` i have a whole bunch of orphaned packages. forgive me for expanding the scope of this post, but how can i go about removing those packages?

Comment: If you know what the missing repo is, you could add it back, then use the `ppa-purge` package to remove all the stuff that came from it.  I haven't used deborphan in a long time; I seem to remember that I decided it was dangerous.

Comment: @Lemma You can use synaptic: https://askubuntu.com/q/44930/1004020

Comment: @OrganicMarble Sorry for the lack of updates. I'm having difficulty finding which repo i need to re-add then purge.

Comment: @DanielT's suggestion might be the way then.

Comment: @OrganicMarble ok after some significant struggling, it's time for me to further reveal how little i know. how does one add the jammy-updates repo? it turns out i'm the only person on the internet to ever need to do this lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found! I simply performed `sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates main universe restricted multiverse"` then `sudo apt update` then finally `sudo apt install steam`. Thanks to @OrganicMarble and @DanielT

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out!